# ¿Cómo debo escribir la frase "En espanol" para ser publicada en la website de una empresa?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, expresiones, pronombres, preposiciones

Necesito hacer un anuncio en la web sobre idiomas puedo usar "en espanol" "En espanol" or En Espanol". ¿Cuál es correcto?

Comment: Supongo que sabes que debe ser "español" y que la pregunta trata del uso de mayúsculas, ¿no?

Answer (score 2):

Creo que depende del contexto en el que la estés utilizando, ¿está dentro de un enunciado?. En general, yo diría que se debe escribir: *En español*

> Las palabras con que se designan lenguas son nombres comunes, razón por la que deben escribirse siempre con minúscula inicial

https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/uso-de-mayuscula-4077/

Comment: Podrías editar esta contribución por favor e incluir aquí las partes relevantes del artículo enlazado que explican porqué la opción que propones es la más adecuada? Gracias.